# How do i create a loop for my function? I've tested it over and over, but it's not doing what i need

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, loops

So, as the code below follows

```
    #!/usr/bin python

#! Primary Imports
import os
import socket
import time
import sys


def client():
    s = socket.socket()  # Create a socket object
    s.connect(('46.166.185.139', 1337))  # Bind to the port
    print("Press CTRL+C To exit.")
    message = raw_input("Message: ")
    s.sendall(message)
client()
```

I'm trying to get the s.sendall(message) function to loop over, as to send multiple messages without restarting the script.
i have tried tons of experiments and methods.

Comment: We see what you're trying to do, but what's your issue? What were you attempts, and where did they fail?

Comment: Question seems to be missing a `for` or `while`loop, no?

Comment: Read more about python, notably its [while](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#while) construct or [for](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) loop

Comment: `while True: message = raw_input("Message: ");  s.sendall(message)`

Comment: Actually, you might need some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) and use [select](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html)

Comment: @t.m.adam , I'm trying to make it to where after the s.sendall(message) function is done, it doesn't close/

Comment: `while True` is an infinite loop, it won't 'close' untill you interrupt it.